# return $pdf->stream doesn't load the logo - DomPDF Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Good night,

I have an HTML that has a logo (image). When I give a return view, I view the page normally:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf', array_merge($request->all(),['logo'=>$baseImage])); 
view('pdf.pdf', array_merge($request->all(),['logo'=>$baseImage]));
```

However, when I change the second line it generates the pdf, but without the logo:

```
return $pdf->stream('teste.pdf', array_merge($request->all(),['logo'=>$baseImage]));
```

Base Image - Controller

```
public function pdf (Request $request){                 
    $baseImage = Storage::get('public/logo.png');       
    $baseImage = base64_encode($baseImage);
    $baseImage = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$baseImage;
    $customPaper = array(0,0,360,360);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf', array_merge($request->all(),['logo'=>$baseImage])); 
    return $pdf->stream('teste.pdf');
}
```

So the logo appears:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="width: 25%;"> <img src="{{$logo}}" width='100%' height="auto"/> </td>
```

Comment: Does this comment helps? https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2238#issuecomment-747600381

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, dompdf has some weird traits, for images instead of server url or relative pathes, use server path, so change your image src to something like this:

```
<img src="{{ public_path($logo) }}">
```

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but the image broke. The public_path is C:\xampp\htdocs\entidades\public and the logo is there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdf', array_merge($request->all(),['logo'=>$baseImage])); 
return $pdf->stream('teste.pdf');
```

then in view file

```
 <img src="{{public_path($logo)}}"/>
```

**Note :** public path point to laravel public folder.

Ref: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/344

Updated:
Since you are fetching image from storage and converting into base64.So i believe  actual image path is in `storage/app/public/logo.png` so  in view you can do following

```
  <img src="{{$logo}}"/>
```

Another option is to create symbolic link to storage.So run following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create shortcut folder in public folder so  no need to convert to base64 etc..

```
  <img src="{{public_path('storage/logo.png')}}"/>
```